# Orkut application development. How to start?

Tags: asp.net

I am an asp.net developer and would like to create an application to be deployed in orkut application.Where should i start from ? Whats the steps ? Is ASP.NET is a must to develop an application  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Orkut developer page](http://code.google.com/apis/orkut/) would probably be the best place to start.  I haven't developed for Orkut directly, but I've done some development using OpenSocial, which the Orkut API is based on.  It's not tied to specific to a specific server-side language like ASP.NET - you "interact" with Orkut through JavaScript libraries and REST service calls - so an Orkut application could be developed in any language that can produce/consume HTTP.  You can develop your server-side piece in ASP.NET, but it isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple.. Take one example orkut application. Open that application iframe into new tab. Save the source and add this source into your orkut application content section xml. Upload your xml and followthe steps to add that into sandbox.orkut.com. Furnish your application. Submit for production orkut environment. Enjoy.. :)